# Flex file upload to remote server using PHP

Tags: php, apache-flex, file-upload

I am trying to upload the files to the remote server using PHP with Flex interface. If it's not localhost, it shows the security error. I have already put the crossdomain.xml in the tomcat web app root directory to allow all the domains. However, the security error is still shown when I tried to upload the file. Any suggestion for this problem? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running your swf from local sandbox, add the location (you're running it from) [here](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html).

Comment: Hi, I have just solved my problem. In the URL, I incidentally added the port no. When I removed the port no in URL, I can already upload the file to the remote server. I have added the crossdomain.xml file in the root directory of tomcat and added this line in mxml application. Security.loadPolicyFile("http://remoteServer.com/xampp/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/crossdomain.xml");  But is it a good way to solve for cross domain problem as the security will be very low?

Comment: "is it a good way" - this is the ONLY way to solve security problems. Read crossdomain.xml [specification](http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/download/attachments/64389123/CrossDomain_PolicyFile_Specification.pdf?version=1) for details. BTW, you don't need to call Security.loadPolicyFile, if your crossdomain.xml is located in default location (root for example).